# No secret key when signing with git

Tags: git, gnupg

After setting

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/pablo/.config/gnupg/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096/46F257F2 2014-09-16 [expires: 2015-09-16]
uid       [ultimate] Pablo Olmos de Aguilera Corradini (Personal) <mail@tld.com>
```

And putting the info on gitconfig:

```
[user]
    name = Pablo Olmos de Aguilera Corradini
    email = mail@tld.com
    signinkey = 46F257F2
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

I get:

```
gpg: skipped "Pablo Olmos de Aguilera Corradini <mail@tld.com>": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

As you can see the keys actually exists (they also appears when running `gpg --list-secret-keys`). If I remove everything from `gitconfig`, and try to do it only with `-S`, I get the same error, which makes me think that git is passing my user name and email to gpg, and the `uid` includes the "comment" `(Personal)`, so it doesn't found any:

```
$ gpg --list-keys "Pablo Olmos de Aguilera Corradini <mail@tld.com>"
gpg: error reading key: No public key
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug from git, or it is the expected result and I'm missing something :).

PS.- My guess is that I could create another `uid` but **without** a comment, and it should work.

Comment: For signing only the secret key is needed. Therefore the output of `gpg --list-keys` is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you using the same user for listing the keys and trying to sign with git?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git commit signing failed: secret key not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810467/git-commit-signing-failed-secret-key-not-available)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a typo in your gitconfig. Should be *signingkey*, not *signinkey*

Comment: That's one reason why you should use `git config` instead of manually editing entries in the `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: ARGH, that's stupid. I actually did use `git config`, but it seems I made that change by hand without noticing it :C. Marking your answer as accepted of course.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding an additional cause and solution that hasn't been covered yet**

For me, the cause was my signing key expired. I remembered to remove it from my keyring and generate a new one, but I forgot to update the hash of my signing key in my global `.gitconfig`. Following the directions in [the GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key) solved the issue, quoted here for posterity:

1. Open Git Bash
2. If you have previously configured Git to use a different key format when signing with `--gpg-sign`, unset this configuration so the default format of `openpgp` will be used.

   ```bash
   git config --global --unset gpg.format
   ```
3. Use the `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long` command to list the long form of the GPG keys for which you have both a public and private key. A private key is required for signing commits or tags.

   ```bash
   gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
   ```

   **Note:** Some GPG installations on Linux may require you to use `gpg2 --list-keys --keyid-format LONG` to view a list of your existing keys instead. In this case you will also need to configure Git to use `gpg2` by running `git config --global gpg.program gpg2`.
4. From the list of GPG keys, copy the long form of the GPG key ID you'd like to use. In this example, the GPG key ID is `3AA5C34371567BD2`:

   ```bash
   $ gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long
   /Users/hubot/.gnupg/secring.gpg
   ------------------------------------
   sec   4096R/3AA5C34371567BD2 2016-03-10 [expires: 2017-03-10]
   uid                          Hubot <hubot@example.com>
   ssb   4096R/4BB6D45482678BE3 2016-03-10
   ```
5. To set your primary GPG signing key in Git, paste the text below, substituting in the GPG primary key ID you'd like to use. In this example, the GPG key ID is `3AA5C34371567BD2`:

   ```bash
   git config --global user.signingkey 3AA5C34371567BD2
   ```

   Alternatively, when setting a subkey include the `!` suffix. In this example, the GPG subkey ID is `4BB6D45482678BE3`:

   ```bash
   git config --global user.signingkey 4BB6D45482678BE3!
   ```
6. Optionally, to configure Git to sign all commits by default, enter the following command:

   ```bash
   git config --global commit.gpgsign true
   ```